# Opening the Apple TV App Store

Tags: tvos

Trying to build a tvOS app and one of the use cases I have is to be able to link off and open another app in the Apple TV App Store directly on a button click. Can someone please share a code snippet to enable this?

Answer (score 13):

I have figured this out by examining the device console output. The trick is to use the `com.apple.TVAppStore` scheme instead of `itms-apps`. Example (Swiss App Store):

```
com.apple.TVAppStore://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/youtube/id544007664?mt=8
```

In fact, the `https` scheme is also working, but it's then transformed into `com.apple.TVAppStore` anyway.

Comment: It also worked for me!! The url I've used is: "com.apple.TVAppStore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/name-of-the-app/id1067674552?mt=8"

Comment: @GarySabo did you find another way?

Comment: @VV used to work well, last time I tested was on 13.2 I think

Answer (score 9):

Just tested this on tvOS:

```
if let appStoreURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wee-puzzles/id1035425291?mt=8") {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appStoreURL)
}
```

It works and opens the App Store page of your app on Apple TV. It's the same as iOS.

Comment: Doesn't work on my New Apple TV. Any special app you have?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this **is not possible** with the current tvOS.

On iOS, as advised by Apple in [QA1629](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1629/_index.html), we would do:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

The above request goes through Safari which does not exist on tvOS. Therefore, it won't work.

However, [Custom URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) are supported on tvOS which might help at least a bit.

Comment: On the `tvOS` developer forums there are a couple of posts of users asking the same question. All posts end the same with a post suggestion to file a bug report on https://bugreport.apple.com. Filed bug `23656992`. Perhaps the more bugs apple receives it will increase their attention to it and give us a method for doing it.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the solution for Swift 4:**
Replace `XXXXXXX`with your app id.
With this solution its possible to create an appstore link for a not yet released app because only the app id (known from appstore connect) is needed.

```
guard let tvOSAppStoreUrl = URL(string: "com.apple.TVAppStore://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXX?mt=8") else {
  return
}

UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: It's working for me. Options and completion handler can be ignored

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works ! Just use the link provided by Apple's [link maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/).
For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://geo.itunes.apple.com/fr/app/math-champions-jeux-calcul/id561572290?mt=8"]]
```

**Do not** modify the link by removing the language or the name of the app like you can on iOS.

Comment: This does not seem to work on TvOS.Returns 1 though. Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible using `SKStoreProductViewController` in StoreKit.
But apparently, that too is `_TVOS_PROHIBITED`.

**[SKStoreProductViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL you get from iTunes. For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://geo.itunes.apple.com/fr/app/math-champions-jeux-calcul/id561572290?mt=8"]]
```

Similar to what the above answers said. But, in order for this to work, your app must be set up as a universal purchase for iOS and tvOS, which is very easy to set up: [Universal Purchase of iOS and tvOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/support/universal-purchase/).