# How to link to a tvOS app page on the Apple TV App Store

Tags: app-store, tvos, apple-tv

I want to link to my own app or other apps store page from inside my app (for example to rate my app). Could be in a way this page is opened inside my app and not directly open the App Store app with app page (it is possible on iOS).

Can't find a way to do that. Methods that works on iOS doesn't work here apparently.

Tried:

1. itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id
2. https://itunes.apple.com/app/id

I know it could be done because I saw apps on the App Store that does exactly that.

Comment: There is no Safari or web browser on the Apple TV, so I think it will need a specific URL Scheme that can be handle by the App Store app directly.

Comment: edit: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163334/opening-the-tvos-app-store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening the TVOS app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163334/opening-the-tvos-app-store)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend iOS app to tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489992/how-to-extend-ios-app-to-tvos)

Comment: @NicolasS That discuss opening another app on tvOS which is completely different issue. Stefan that discussing extending an iOS app to support tvOS with same code. That also irrelevant.
Please don't just vote for closing if you don't understand the question.

Comment: @NicolasS Btw, I saw other apps on store that does exactly that. So there is a way of doing it...URL Scheme isn't relevant because I don't want to open another app but the app store (itms-apps doesn't work)