# Does tvOS provide a standard alert for force-updating app?

Tags: swift, internationalization, app-store, uialertview, tvos

Sometimes users have to update app to be compatible with server API, so I need to show a must-update-now alert. Is there some build-in message in all supported languages in tvOS or I have to provide such message myself for all languages?

And how do I go to App Store page for my app in tvOS?

Update: I see that there is [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy)/[Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren) library for ObjC/Swift so it looks like I will have to translate it myself.

Comment: No, you'd have to parse the app info and check if there is a new version available yourself. To open the Apple TV App Store refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33163334/2108547

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I need the message.

Comment: You need to know how to present a UIAlertView?

Comment: I need the message for about 100 languages and wonder if there is one in tvOS itself.

Comment: No. You would have to create your own message and localize it.

Comment: Pretty sure Install Updates Automatically is enabled by default on Apple TV so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Yes, but for those users who disable it (or did not get updated in time) the app won't work until it's been updated.

Comment: Were you able to find out if Harpy/Siren libraries work with tvOS?